# nginx or apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apache vs Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/157520/apache-vs-nginx)

What do you prefer? Please, only answer those who use(d) both. What is better for bigger sites and what is easier to configurate?

I never used nginx because I have no PCs/servers to test it on

Answer (score 0):

I've used both systems very extensively.  As Cucumber suggested, it depends to some degree on what you want to do, but I'd lean heavily towards nginx as it's small, lightweight, and fast, but still does everything you need for most situations.  I also prefer it's model for executing dynamic content -- it has no support for running it in-process.  This does make setting up some forms of dynamic content "harder" than it would be in Apache (for example, `mod_php` makes PHP trivial in Apache, while in nginx it requires some FastCGI setup) but the nginx way is *better* -- more secure, and better separation of concerns.

Answer (score -1):

The choice depends on what you want to do. If you need a static web server + php, then use nginx. For databases Apache - the best solution. For some production systems used ligaments nginx + apache  where nginks acts as a proxy. 
And believe me, if you configured Apache, you can easily set up nginx, because nginx is very easy in settings.

Comment: Since you spelled the name Apache wrongly **three times** I'm not sure you can have used it...

Comment: @pavium - or, *maybe*, it's because his native language isn't *English*, but Russian.

Comment: In that case, he *almost* certainly used `nginx`. I'm thinking of giving it a try, myself.